# Can I reuse Httpclient in Integration tests in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dispose

I have an `Asp.net core 6 Web api`.

I make Integration tests with `xUnit` following the pattern [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0). `WebApplicationFactory` creates a client which the tests can use to make calls to the application instance.

Now, `xUnit` runs the class constructor for every test. To share a member between all tests in a test class, you need to use a xUnit class fixture. This is the example from MSDN:

```
public class IndexPageTests : 
    IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> 
        _factory;

    public IndexPageTests(
        CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            });
    }
```

I don't understand - why they put the CreateClient method in the constructor? Obviously, it will create a new client for every test. Why don't we create a separate Fixture class, create the client there and just inject it in the Test class?
For example:

```
public class TestFixture 
{
    public TestFixture()
    {
       var factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup>();
       Client = factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            });
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; }
}

public class TestClass : IClassFixture<TestFixture>
{
    private readonly TestFixture _fixture;

    public TestClass(TestFixture fixture)
    {
       _fixture = fixture;
    }


    [Fact]
    public async Task FirstTest()
    {
       // use the fixture client directly
       await _fixture.Client.GetAsync("..../url");
    }
}
```

Does anyone see a problem with this approach? Memory leaks or other issues?
Is the fact that we instantiate `CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup>()` in the fixture constructor and not disposing it afterwards - causing memory problems, etc?

Comment: One reason could be that each test should be **independent**. So, if you recreate the HttpClient every time (rather than reusing it across multiple test cases) then you can be sure that you start each and every test with a clean HttpClient. One malfunctioning test would not influence other tests by sharing the same reusable HttpClient.